# Convert jsonb comma separated values into a json object using a psql script

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I have a table in postgresql that has two columns:

```
               Table "schemaname.tablename"
 Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default
--------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 _key   | character varying |           | not null |
 value  | jsonb             |           |          |
Indexes:
    "tablename_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (_key)
```

and I'd like to convert a nested property value of the jsonb that looks like this:

```
{
    "somekey": "[k1=v1, k2=v2, k3=v2]",
}
```

into this:

```
{
    "somekey":  [
        "java.util.LinkedHashMap",
        {
            "k1": "v1",
            "k2": "v2",
            "k3": "v3"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've managed to parse the comma separted string into an array of strings but aside from having to still apply another split on '=' I don't really know how to do the actual UPDATE on all rows of the table and generate the proper jsonb value for "somekey" key.

```
select regexp_split_to_array(RTRIM(LTRIM(value->>'somekey','['),']'),',') from schemaname.tablename;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one (self-contained test data):

```sql
WITH tablename (_key, value) AS (
    VALUES
        ('test', '{"somekey":"[k1=v1, k2=v2, k3=v2]"}'::jsonb),
        ('second', '{"somekey":"[no one=wants to, see=me, with garbage]"}'::jsonb),
        ('third', '{"somekey":"[some,key=with a = in it''s value, some=more here]"}'::jsonb)
    )
SELECT
    tab._key,
    jsonb_insert(
        '{"somekey":["java.util.LinkedHashMap"]}', -- basic JSON structure
        '{somekey,0}', -- path to insert after
        jsonb_object( -- create a JSONB object on-the-fly from the key-value array
            array_agg(key_values) -- aggregate all key-value rows into one array
        ),
        true -- we want to insert after the matching element, not before it
    ) AS json_transformed
FROM
    tablename AS tab,
    -- the following is an implicit LATERAL join (function based on eahc row for previous table)
    regexp_matches( -- produces multiple rows
        btrim(tab.value->>'somekey', '[]'), -- as you started with
        '(\w[^=]*)=([^,]*)', -- define regular expression groups for keys and values
        'g' -- we want all key-value sets
    ) AS key_values
GROUP BY 1
;
```

...resulting in:

```
  _key  |                                           json_transformed                                            
--------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 second | {"somekey": ["java.util.LinkedHashMap", {"see": "me", "no one": "wants to"}]}
 third  | {"somekey": ["java.util.LinkedHashMap", {"some": "more here", "some,key": "with a = in it's value"}]}
 test   | {"somekey": ["java.util.LinkedHashMap", {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v2"}]}
(3 rows)
```

I hope the inline comments explain how it works in enough detail.

#### Without requiring aggregate/group by:

The following requires no grouping as we don't need aggregate function `array_agg`, but are a little bit less strict on the key-value format and will break a query easily because of some data (the previous variant will just drop some key-value):

```sql
WITH tablename (_key, value) AS (
    VALUES
        ('test', '{"somekey":"[k1=v1, k2=v2, k3=v2]"}'::jsonb),
        ('second', '{"somekey":"[no one=wants to, see=me, with garbage]"}'::jsonb)
    )
SELECT
    _key,
    jsonb_insert(
        '{"somekey":["java.util.LinkedHashMap"]}', -- basic JSON structure
        '{somekey,0}', -- path to insert after
        jsonb_object( -- create a JSONB object on-the-fly from the key-value array
            key_values -- take the keys + values as split using the function
        ),
        true -- we want to insert after the matching element, not before it
    ) AS json_transformed
FROM
    tablename AS tab,
    -- the following is an implicit LATERAL join (function based on eahc row for previous table)
    regexp_split_to_array( -- produces an array or keys and values: [k, v, k, v, ...]
        btrim(tab.value->>'somekey', '[]'), -- as you started with
        '(=|,\s*)' -- regex to match both separators
    ) AS key_values
;
```

...results into:

```
  _key  |                                json_transformed                                
--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 test   | {"somekey": ["java.util.LinkedHashMap", {"k1": "v1", "k2": "v2", "k3": "v2"}]}
 second | {"somekey": ["java.util.LinkedHashMap", {"see": "me", "no one": "wants to"}]}
(2 rows)
```

Feeding it with garbage (as in the "second" row before) or with an `=` character in the value (as in the "third" row before) would result in the following error here:

```
ERROR:  array must have even number of elements
```

Comment: This is super helpful @Ancoron! I just have two issues that I'm facing right now. One small issue which is related to the regex not supporting multiple words for keys/values and another big issue is that if you remove the WHERE clause this code merges all key/values into a single row and I need to generate a json object per row.

Comment: second issue I think can be solved by using a group by _key

Comment: I see. I just had a second look and your initial idea using `regexp_split_to_array` might be superior here, but only as along as no key or value includes characters `,` or `=`. Otherwise, we might need to write a little helper function ourselves. I'll update my solution with a second option.

Comment: I also had a look into existing parsers (e.g. `hstore`), but they are ever less flexible and need pre-processing too. So the (reworked) option using `regexp_matches` looks like the best approach for now in pure SQL.